# How to save model with cloudpickle to databricks DBFS folder and load it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, databricks, pickle

I built a model and my goal is to save the model as a pickle and load it later for scoring. Right now, I am using this code:

```
    #save model as pickle
    import cloudpickle
    pickled = cloudpickle.dumps(final_model)
    
    #load model
    cloudpickle.loads(pickled)
    Output: <econml.dml.causal_forest.CausalForestDML at 0x7f388e70c373>
```

My worry is that with this approach the model will be saved only in a session-variable "pickled" of the notebook in Databricks.

I want the model to be stored in a DBFS storage though, so I can pull this model at any time (even if my notebook session expires) to make it more robust.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `/dbfs/<DBFS path>` to save model using the Local File API (please note that it's not supported on community edition).

But really, I would recommend to rely on the [MLflow to log model & all necessary hyperparameters](https://docs.databricks.com/mlflow/models.html) into MLflow Model Registry - then you can easily load model using model name instead of of using paths.  With MLflow you can get more benefits, like, tracking multiple model versions, using stages, etc.